# How to use a document with same type as nested in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search. 
I need to use a self reference in nested documents.

```
Example: Employee will have manager(Himself an employee).
```

fields:

```
employee_id - long, 
employee_name - string 
manager(document of another employee)
```

I am able to do mapping for employee id, employee name. I am struggling to do the mapping for manager field. Do I need to map the complete set of fields(emplyee_id, employee_name) in nested?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With nested document you will have to repeat entire mappings for manager and manager of the manager and manager of the manager of the manager if you want to store several levels. It might be better to represent this as parent-child relationship.